# DOM and ngRepeat Relation

Tags: angularjs

We know that The ngRepeat directive will repeat the instance of the element upon which it is declared.
The question is when we inspect element in firebug we are able to see the corresponding `html` which got generated but when we see the source of the same file there is no corresponding `html`. Why?

Comment: You need to check that with Inspect Element . View Source shows the response that was downloaded from server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the new elements are generated dinamically. That is JavaScript.
The source is the HTML that the server gives you.

Try to di it:
Open Firebug and remove all the elements in your HTML. Then see the source (Ctrl + U). Check all the elements still there.

Comment: Ok put some light on DOM

Comment: Ok I did what you said but the source remained same but upon removal of elements from firebug the things got reflected on the page also

Comment: Thanks a lot brother.

Comment: All elements still there because that is WHAT the SERVER gives you... Then you changed that, but Control + U will show you the original message

Answer (score 0):

The extra elements are generated by Angular in JavaScript on the client. You won't see them in the initial html response because they haven't been generated yet.